# can I force perl to inline subroutines?

Tags: perl

I know non-constant subroutines usually will not be inlined, since they can be redefined on the fly.  However, I have code where inlined subroutines would actually offer a small but non-trivial optimization; but I don't want to unroll them myself since it would make the code much harder to read.

Is there some way to make Perl inline these methods, a way to indicate that the subroutine will not be modified at runtime and I want the interpreter to inline during the preprocessing phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants can be folded, but Perl subs are never inlined. Practically, they can't be. [macro](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?macro) and [Macro](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Macro) attempt to provide inlinable subs, but I don't know how reliable they are. You will definitely find limitations.